# Release in viewDidUnload and dealloc both?

Tags: objective-c, memory-management, uiviewcontroller

I have been under the assumption for a while that `viewDidUnload` is always called when a controller is deallocated.  Is this a correct assumption?

I've just been exploring some odd things, and set a breakpoint in my controller's `viewDidUnload` and it's `dealloc`.  It appears that `dealloc` is called, but the `viewDidUnload` method is never called.  I even added a `self.view = nil` to my `dealloc` and it still didn't seem to call it.

Does this mean that retained view objects I have been releasing in the `viewDidUnload` method also need to be released in my `dealloc` method to be sure they really go away?

I know there are many other questions on StackOverflow about `viewDidUnload`, but none specifically address this issue about duplication of release statements between the 2 methods.

---

A more concrete exmaple in a fresh project on the 3.1.2 SDK:

```
@implementation TestViewController

@synthesize label;

- (IBAction)push {
    TestViewController *controller = [[[TestViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"TestViewController" bundle:nil] autorelease];
    [self.navigationController pushViewController:controller animated:YES];
}

- (void)viewDidUnload {
    self.label = nil;
    NSLog(@"viewDidUnload was called");
}

- (void)dealloc {
    [super dealloc];
    NSLog(@"label retain count: %i", [label retainCount]);
}

@end
```

My app delegate creates a simple navigation controller with one of these as it's root controller.  When I tap the button linked to `push` 3 times, and then hit the back button three times, the following output is generated.

```
ViewDidUnloadTest[2887:207] label retain count: 2
ViewDidUnloadTest[2887:207] label retain count: 2
ViewDidUnloadTest[2887:207] label retain count: 2
```

Which is 2 higher that I would think it would be.  Retained once by the view and once by the controller.  But after the `dealloc` I would have expected the view to be gone releasing my label, and the controller to be gone calling `viewDidUnload` and releasing it.  Although there may be an `autorelease` in there throwing off the count at this point.

But at least it's clear that `viewDidUnload` is not getting called at all, which contrary to this answer here: [Are viewDidUnload and dealloc always called when tearing down a UIViewController?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1768076/are-viewdidunload-and-dealloc-always-called-when-tearing-down-a-uiviewcontroller)

Perhaps I should simply call `[self viewDidUnload]` in all my dealloc methods on controllers?  Worse than can happen is that I set a property to nil twice, right?

Answer (score 20, accepted):

Unless you need to break a retain cycle, you should *generally* only be releasing objects in your `dealloc` method.  `viewDidUnload` is an exception; it is invoked in low memory situations and should be used to release anything that you can.

If you do need to release them anywhere else, then always set the reference to nil after the `release`.  That'll protect your app from blowing up later (likely in `dealloc`).

Note that the documentation quite explicitly calls out that the view property will already be nil when `viewDidUnload` is called.

Comment: So you are saying "Yes, you need to release retained properties in your `dealloc` even if you release and nullify them in your `viewDidUnload` method"?

Comment: Exactly;  viewDidUnload is for low memory situations & dealloc is for cleanup.  The two are orthogonal.

Comment: This is a very confusing point coming from the examples! Most examples show things being set to nil in the viewDidUnload. What it fails to explain is that after something is set to nil, you can't release it and expect it to deallocate! Without taking note of this, you'll end up with memory leaks all over the place. Thanks for your helpful post.

Comment: @jocull Setting a retained property to nil will in fact release it, which will make it deallocate as long as you don't have another retained reference somewhere else.

Comment: @Nick I couldn't get it to happen that way. Can you point me at any documentation that further explains this?

Comment: That's the whole point of a retained property - when you call `setFoo:`, the old `foo` value gets released, and the new one gets retained. Read about the `retain` property attribute here: http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/ObjectiveC/Articles/ocProperties.html%23//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP30001163-CH17-SW2

Comment: @Nick Does this only happen if you use `[setFoo:nill];` or does it also work if you use `somevar.Foo = nil;` ?

Comment: @jocull `[foo setBar:nil];` will be compiled to exactly the same binary as `foo.bar = nil;` - they are exactly equivalent (as long as foo has a `setBar:` method declared).

Comment: Note that [foo setBar:nil] and foo.bar = nil both release a retained property, bar = nil (if bar is local to the call) will NOT and you will have a leak. You would need to do [bar release], bar = nil; in that case.

Comment: Yup -- and `[bar release];` without `bar = nil;` happily creates a dangling pointer!

Comment: I have create a object of class and release and set nil it. and re alloc init it. . . . but the released object not kill it task. how i kill all the tasks started by the object.