# Object release in Objective-C: Why release an object twice in viewDidUnload and dealloc method?

Tags: objective-c, release, dealloc, viewdidunload

I have a question about object release in objective-c. I saw some sample codes in Chapter 9 of "Beginning iphone 4 Development"(Page 287). The sample code release an object twice: both in viewDidUnload and dealloc method. Here are the sample codes:

```
- (void)viewDidUnload {
self.list = nil;
[childController release], childController = nil;}

- (void)dealloc {
[list release];
[childController release];
[super dealloc];}
```

*childController* is declared as an instance of *UIViewController* subclass. Why is it released in both *viewDidUnload* and *dealloc* method? Since *childController* is already released in *viewDidUnload*, is it necessary to release it again in *dealloc* method? Based my understanding I will write the code like:

```
- (void)viewDidUnload {
self.list = nil;
childController = nil;}
- (void)dealloc {
[list release];
[childController release];
[super dealloc];}
```

Thanks,
Sam

Comment: there is no need to release childController twice. I really can't find a (justified) reason why someone would do it

Comment: possible duplicate of [When should I release objects in -(void)viewDidUnload rather than in -dealloc?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1158788/when-should-i-release-objects-in-voidviewdidunload-rather-than-in-dealloc)

Comment: @Mark, you're right. Dup with *When should I release objects in -(void)viewDidUnload rather than in -dealloc?*

Answer (score 3):

The problem is `viewDidUnload` is not guaranteed to be called every time like `dealloc` method. (check [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1768076/are-viewdidunload-and-dealloc-always-called-when-tearing-down-a-uiviewcontroller)).

The reason to release objects in `viewDidUnload` is to avoid memory leaks. Since `viewDidUnload` is called when there's a low memory warning, you do want to clean up to avoid troubles in that case.

And also calling release on `nil` will not cause any problem, so it is safe to call release on retained objects in your `dealloc` method assuming the pointers are set to nil after been released elsewhere (like in `viewDidUnload` in your example).

Comment: But if viewDidUnload is called on memory warning and after that dealloc is called won't you than release an object that is pointing to nil???

Comment: If you release an object that is pointing to nil, than yes. But I'm trying to find out what is really happening after memory warning level 3 (last level)

Comment: @sam-wei sending any messages to nil will not cause any problem, they will be safely ignored.

Answer (score 0):

In order to optimize available memory, is a good practice to implement lazy getters (actually lazy initializers) in UIViewControllers and release easily reallocable objects in **viewDidUnload**.
A (simplified) lazy getter is something like:

```
- (UIView *)footerView {
    if (_footerView) {
        return _footerView;
    }
    UIView *view = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:A_FRAME];
    return (_footerView = view);
}
```

so, in the **viewDidUnload** I will release **_footerView**, because I can retrieve it later without effort. The release of **_footerView** in dealloc method, is not an error, because:
1) in objective c is ok to send messages to nil objects, 2) dealloc won't be executed at the same time as **viewDidUnload** but later

Comment: I am not very quite clear about what you said. Why don't you release view [view release] in footerView? Will it lead to memory leak?

Comment: no, it won't leak, because the retainCount is 1 (after [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:A_FRAME]) and it will decrease to 0 later. I'm simply assigning the allocated view to _footerView (which is nil), I'm not retaining the view again after the assignment!

Answer (score 0):

I've investigated a little bit because I was not sure. And all you need to know is here: [When should I release objects in -(void)viewDidUnload rather than in -dealloc?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1158788/when-should-i-release-objects-in-voidviewdidunload-rather-than-in-dealloc)

Basically, in viewDidUnload you release objects that you've created in the beginning of view's life cycle (loadView, viewDid load and so on). So if your viewController receives memory warning it will unload a view and reload it again and then your objects will be released in viewDidUnload and initialized again in loadView/viewDidLoad/ect

Comment: Thank you, @paxx. I am reading *When should I release objects in -(void)viewDidUnload rather than in -dealloc?* now.