# Programmatically unloading all views on iOS Device

Tags: objective-c, cocoa-touch, viewdidload, viewdidunload, appdelegate

*Edited title*

I am using Core Data to store some data I collect from my server. In `appDelegate`'s `applicationDidBecomeActive`, I check if the app needs to download new data (from a version-variable on my server). If it has old information, it downloads the new data.

The problem is, in some of my views, I have `tableViews`. And these get their data from an array of data extracted from `Core Data` in `viewDidLoad`.
When opening the app, and the `viewDidLoad` has already been called, and THEN it updates the data in `Core Data`, when I then enter the views with `tableView`, all the rows are wrong. In my case, all the rows shows the same image as the first row, and none of them have any text. I am thinking that the old array has some corrupt data which needs to be reloaded.. As I am writing this I realize that `viewDidLoad` needs to be called again. Or at least the code in `viewDidLoad`. I do not want to move it to `viewDidAppear` or `willAppear`, because that will mean that this happenes everytime. 
I thought about force-restarting the process, but I read that this wasn't possible, and that Apple would reject a force quit anyway.

Actually, I kinda just need to know how to programmatically unload all views from `AppDelegate`, so that they will have to call `viewDidLoad` again. Or force a `viewDidLoad` again.

Comment: You should use a `NSFetchedResultsController` for the table view. A FRC tracks changes to the managed object context automatically.

Comment: @MartinR - Yes, I probably should.. But from the very beginning I wrote the code to get data from the NSArray with a fetchRequest in the viewDidLoad. I have five tableviews doing this, until I realized I should go with Core Data. This is the very last bug of my app (currently), and the only thing missing is a "unload all views"-command, or "force viewDidLoad next time"-command.

Comment: You could move the code from `viewDidLoad` to a separate method `updateData` method. In `viewWillAppear` you can then check `if (needUpdate) [self updateData];` . - Tampering with the view controllers views does not sound like a good idea.

Comment: Sounds like a good idea.. Thanks. Will try to figure out how to set/check the needUpdate.

Comment: ... or register for the `NSManagedObjectContextObjectsDidChangeNotification` and reload the data only if that notification is posted.

Comment: Yea, I'm pretty new to objective-c, and haven't touched the notification-system yet, so I'll try the first idea first, and read up on notifications if that solution runs slow.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you cannot use a fetched results controller, you could
 register for the `NSManagedObjectContextObjectsDidChangeNotification`:

```
[[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self
    selector:@selector(contextChanged:)
    name:NSManagedObjectContextObjectsDidChangeNotification
    object:theManagedObjectContext];
```

and reload the data only if necessary:

```
- (void)contextChanged:(NSNotification *)note
{
    // reload your table data
}
```

Don't forget to remove the observer, e.g. in `dealloc`:

```
[[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] removeObserver:self]
```

Comment: What do you mean by "remove the observer"? With the use of ARC I do not use dealloc. Do I still need to remove it elsewhere?

Comment: Each `addObserver` needs a matching `removeObserver`. Even with ARC you can have a `dealloc` method for this purpose.

Comment: I have never used dealloc as I started with iOS after ARC came. Would it make the same result if I put that line of code in the unload method `viewDidUnload`?

Comment: According to http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1768076/are-viewdidunload-and-dealloc-always-called-when-tearing-down-a-uiviewcontroller you cannot be sure that `viewDidUnload` is called before `dealloc`.

Comment: Okay, the notification worked great, but I still don't get the whole dealloc thing. Thought I'd just run with it, but I get an error with that last code you provided.. Sure that is correct? It says "No known instance method for selector 'addObserver:'"

Comment: My fault, it is `removeObserver`.  I have updated the answer.